# Multihomed Windows 2008 R2 outgoing connection

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

I have Windows 2008 R2 Server with several directly connected networks and interface with default route to the Internet.

Today I noticed (and then checked with Wireshark), that if I make request to host on connected network that is down, windows tries to make connection from correct interface, but then it tries to connect from interface with default route.

How should I configure Windows to avoid such behavior?
So that if no host answers in connected network, no other interfaces is used for making connection?

Answer (score 0):

I've found [KB2903590](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2903590), but it does not explain why traffic goes out via wrong interface